# Topic to be subscribed to using laser_height_estimation

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I would like to give a try using laser_height_estimation package to estimate height of my flying robot as could be found [here](http://answers.ros.org/question/29373/strange-laser_scan_matcher-performance?comment=29388#comment-29388). What topic should I subscribe to? I couldn't find it in its tutorial.

Thanks in advance.

EDIT:

I found there are 2 of them: /mav/height_to_base and /mav/height_to_footprint. Which one is more relevant and which are the datatypes of them?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/29413/topic-to-be-subscribed-to-using-laser_height_estimation/) by [alfa_80](https://answers.ros.org/users/121/alfa_80/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1053 on 2012-03-09

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

With our quadrotor, the base frame is at the center of motion, and the footprint frame is where the legs are. So when the MAV is on the ground, the height to base might be arund 0.18 meters, but the height to footprint will be close to 0.

You can subscribe to whichever topic is more convenient in your case.

Make sure your include a static publisher from base to footprint.

The messages published are of type [mav_msgs::Height](http://www.ros.org/doc/api/mav_msgs/html/msg/Height.html).

---

Originally posted by [Ivan Dryanovski](https://answers.ros.org/users/79/ivan-dryanovski/) with karma: 4954 on 2012-03-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [alfa_80](https://answers.ros.org/users/121/alfa_80/) on 2012-03-09**:
But then, do you think, will this package work for my hardware configuration as in the provided link? I'm worried, it's meant to work with your hardware setup(laser mounting) only.

**Comment by [alfa_80](https://answers.ros.org/users/121/alfa_80/) on 2012-03-09**:
I couldn't configure your msg type correctly, am I right to include this  "#include <mav_msgs/Height.h>" and in manifest.xml, i add "  

"?

**Comment by [Ivan Dryanovski](https://answers.ros.org/users/79/ivan-dryanovski/) on 2012-03-09**:
yes that include looks correct